# How to return date fields in CEST timezone

Tags: loopbackjs

by default Loopbackjs returns dates like this :  "2018-07-03T07:59:36.179Z"

I'd like to get it in CEST format.

Is there a parameter or something to have it by default ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to store dates in your local timezone instead of UTC in your database connector, you could configure it in your datasource config. It will then return the date as it is on the DB.

```
"host": "localhost",
"port": "3306",
"database": "testDB",
"username": "root",
"password": "root",
"name": "test_name",
"connector": "mysql",
"timezone": "Europe/Belgium"
```

You could check out the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for dealing with datetime. It makes the job a whole lot easier.